# How do I convert a list of object into a single object/array?

Tags: javascript

Here I have `products` which is a list of objects. After filtered, selectedProduct is still a list of objects and thus I have to use `[0]`. In C#, they have something called `SingleOrDefault` which return only a single object after run a LINQ query. In Javascript, do they have something similar?

```js
const products = [{
    id: 5,
    productName: "Logitech Mouse",
    unitprice: 35
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    productName: "Logitech Keyboard",
    unitprice: 40
  }
];

selectedProduct = products.filter(
  prod => prod.id == 6
)

console.log(selectedProduct[0].productName);
```

Comment: Use `.find` instead

Comment: `find` will return the first element which the predicate matches with.